# How can I add a gesture to a UIActionSheet?

Tags: ios, uiactionsheet

In iOS8 ,I want to add a gesture to an `UIActionSheet` so I can close the ActionSheet when I tap on background. but actionsheet.frame is (0,0,0,0),addGestureRecognizer doesn't work,addSubview neither.

Answer (score 0):

I think you can do like this way,

```
UITapGestureRecognizer *tap = [[UITapGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(tapClicked:)];
[self.actionSheet.window addGestureRecognizer:tap];
```

then after you can detect tap on out side of alertView

```
-(void)tapClicked:(UIGestureRecognizer *)gestureRecognizer {
    CGPoint fr = [gestureRecognizer locationInView:self];
    if (fr.y < 0) { // outside Tap
         [self dismissWithClickedButtonIndex:0 animated:YES]; // alertview dismiss method
    }
 }
```

Comment: sorry,I didn't describe my problem properly.I set the "cancelButtonTitle" to nil,So it won't didmiss when I click on the background. Now I've solved the problem by set cancelButtonTitle to something , there is no need to add any other code. thanks for your help,anyway.

Answer (score 0):

You should add the UIGestureRecognizer to the background view rather than the UIActionSheet itself. I've made a sample project, and it works well.

```
#import "ViewController.h"
@interface ViewController () <UIActionSheetDelegate>
// make the UIActionSheet to be a property so that you can track it
@property (nonatomic, strong) UIActionSheet *actionSheet;
@end

@implementation ViewController

- (void)viewDidLoad {
  [super viewDidLoad];
  _actionSheet = [[UIActionSheet alloc] initWithTitle:@"Action Sheet" delegate:self cancelButtonTitle:@"Cancel" destructiveButtonTitle:@"Some button" otherButtonTitles:nil];
  _actionSheet.actionSheetStyle = UIActionSheetStyleAutomatic;

  UITapGestureRecognizer *singleTap = [[UITapGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(singleTap)];
  // add the gestureRecognizer to the background view
  [self.view addGestureRecognizer:singleTap];
}

- (void)singleTap {
  // check nil & visible
  if (_actionSheet && _actionSheet.isVisible) {
    // dismiss with cancel button
    [_actionSheet dismissWithClickedButtonIndex:0 animated:YES];
  }
}

// I pulled out a UIButton to show the UIActionSheet
- (IBAction)showActionSheet:(UIButton *)sender {
  [_actionSheet showInView:self.view];
}
```

Comment: sorry,I didn't describe my problem properly.I set the "cancelButtonTitle" to nil,So it won't didmiss when I click on the background. Now I've solved the problem by set cancelButtonTitle to something , there is no need to add any other code